# SQL percentage calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point

I have created a query in which there is a column that calculates a percentage:

```
SELECT 
     u.User_FirstName
    ,l.[Total Leads]
    ,SUM(s.SalesCount) AS [New Clients]
    ,c.Target
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,0),ROUND((CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,2), SUM(s.SalesCount)) / l.[Total Leads]) * 100, 0))) + '%'
```

As you can see, that last column is my percentage column, which uses a lot of `CONVERT`.  I was wondering if there is a simpler or faster way to get a two-digit percentage in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'm assuming that `SalesCount` and `TotalSales` are integers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel that [rofl pretty well covered how this could be done differently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/58378/41243), but I want to point out what I feel to be an issue.

You really shouldn't be formatting the decimal results as a string. Formatting should be done in whatever application consumes the data you're sending it. As a user, I would be pretty upset to receive a "percentage" that I couldn't do any mathematical analysis on without first splitting out the "%" character, dividing by 100, and *then* formatting it as a percentage natively.

```
Select CONVERT(decimal(5,0), 1.0 * SUM([SalesCount]) / [Total Leads])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use implicit numeric conversion to save you a lot of coding here. Specifically, if you use `100.0` instead of `100` you will do floating-point arithmetic automatically. Consider the following:

```
100.0 * SUM([SalesCount]) / [Total Leads]
```

This will produce a floating point result that is accurate (no integer division).

Now, if you want to display that as a rounded string with no decimal places, I would cast it to a Decimal(5,0), and then a varchar.

```
Select CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(decimal(5,0), 100.0 * SUM([SalesCount]) / [Total Leads])) + '%'
```